# Cannot run django-admin.py startproject in virtual environment, or at all, in Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-admin

I am trying to create a project in a virtual environment in Ubuntu 16.04

I am using Python 3.6

What I do so far is

```
sudo bash

cd Desktop/DamLevels-course2/Damlevels2/

source venv2/bin/activate 

django-admin.py startproject dams
```

The error says: `ImportError: No module named 'secrets'`

I have checked the list of modules in python and secrets is there, but when I try to import to the virtual environment I get an error saying : import: not authorized 'secrets' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028

I tried adding the shebang line as well (#!/usr/bin/env) but that didn't seem to work; running the startproject line again results in the same error message as before.

I am very new to all of this, so I would appreciate fairly simple help.

Comment: If `secrets` is missing, you are not on Python 3.6.

Comment: Also a reminder: don't use Python 3.7, go for 3.8, 3.7 has several problems with Django

Comment: @paaksing How is that related to the question?

Comment: @KlausD. I saw your comment of Python 3.6, so I want to add a reminder for it in case people wanted to upgrade to 3.7

Comment: Hmm ok I installed it, updated the alternatives and set the configuration. However, when I use python3 -V it still says I'm using Python 3.5.2.

Comment: Then you might have misunderstood my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it to work. Instead of using

```
django-admin.py startproject *name*
```

i used

```
django-admin startproject *name*
```

First I had to install `python-django`

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The [Django documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) the command to create a new project is:

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

So to create your project replace "mysite" with "dams", or whatever your project name will be. For example:

```
$ django-admin startproject dams
```

Also, perhaps it was a typo but the package that should be installed is "python3-django", not "python-django". This command will install python3-django.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-django
```

The Django documentation also [references potential problems running django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin). Here is an excerpt mentioning issues between django-admin and django-admin.py.

> **Problems running django-admin**
>
> **command not found: django-admin**
>
> *django-admin* should be on your system path if you installed Django via
> pip. If it’s not on your path, you can find it in
> "site-packages/django/bin", where site-packages is a directory within
> your Python installation. Consider symlinking to *django-admin* from
> some place on your path, such as /usr/local/bin.
>
> If *django-admin* doesn’t work but *django-admin.py* does, you’re probably
> using a version of Django that doesn’t match the version of this
> documentation. *django-admin* is new in Django 1.7.